# Decode a Serialize String and replace special characters

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). But I've been trying to add a decode script to the following Serialize on the JSFiddle (link below) with little success.

I'd like to decode the resulting string and replace the & with + and the = with nothing....and then submit the string. The serialize string keeps on disappearing on me when I add the decode variables. Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/4Nmcx/

Comment: +1 for using the inline tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string.replace("=","").replace("&","+") - for replacing your special characters. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

I think you should bind the 'change' event to the 'form' element.